# AngularJS not evaluating immedietely when using cache reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started to use AngularJS and wanted to use a foreach loop like this

```
<div class="project" ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <a href="projects/[[ project.slug ]]">[[ project.name ]] &raquo;</a>
    <p>{{ trans('project.description') }}: [[ project.description ]]</p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

The projects variable is getting filled by this code.

```
Project.get()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data;
        $scope.loading  = false;
    });
```

and

```
get : function() {
        return $http.get('/api/projects');
    },
```

When I now navigate to the site it works without problems. The data gets evaluated and displayed normally.

But, when I'm doing a reload of the page (Command + R) I can see the AngularJS code for a split second on the page, meaning the user can see `[[ project.name ]]` etc. instead of th evaluated code. What could cause this? is this normal behaviour? `ng-hide` is set to false initially through `$scope.loading  = true;`, a variable which is set to false in the success method of `Project.get()`

---

I think this should be enough code, if you need more, tell me and I provide you with the full code.

Comment: This is normal behavior -- to avoid this use ng-bind or ng-bind-html instead of {{foo}}.

Comment: Hi. So I would do it like this?

`<p ng-bind="[[ project.description ]]"></p>` ? Is this correct?

Comment: In an ng-bind you don't need the brackets:  `<p ng-bind="project.description"></p>`.   (Incidentally in the cases when you *do* need brackets, you need curly, not square.)

Comment: Hi, since I'm using blade.php I changed the brackets from `{{` and `}}` to `[[` and `]]`. 

Thanks for the answer. So ng-bind and just the variable name in there. What If I want to have additional text? Like `ng-bind="project.name &raquo;"`. This doesn't work of course. Would I type the `&raquo;` normally and just build a span around the text that I want to be created by `ng-bind`? i.e. ng-bind replaces text. How do I connect multiple strings?

Comment: `string <span ng-bind="foo"></span> more string <span ng-bind="bar"></span> even more string`.  If that gets too cumbersome you can use ng-cloak, but ng-bind is (slightly) more performant than directly-embedded variables.   (Sorry about the brackets issue, I've never seen someone do that before.)

Comment: Hm, that's a tough one. Performance vs. readability. I kinda find it odd to add a span to every element. Also, another problem I'm seeing is, when I just use ng-bind, then the text that get's evaluated is getting displayed later, but the text, that doesn't need to be evaluated is there and also blinks afterwards. 

So I think ng-cloak would be the better solution if I have mixed output, right? Like as well as normal HTML/PHP as well as AngularJS output

Comment: Extra DOM nodes sort of come with the Angular territory, yeah.  ng-cloak is fine if that's your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is an ajax request there you won't have the javascript object populated immediately so the placeholder will appear there.

You have some options here:

- Use **ng-bind** which is recommended over the use of"{{...}}"
- Use **ng-cloak** which prevents the brief display of raw html templates, as the documentation shows it : [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

---

Comment: Hi. So I would do it like this?

`<p ng-bind="[[ project.description ]]"></p>` ? Is this correct?

Comment: as @Daniel  said alos, yes it should work, but without the '[[' you just add the variable name to that ng-bind